# In graph G finding a cycle with no duplicate vertices of length at least k is NP complete.

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

I know that this problem is similar to the hamming cycle problem, But how can I show that the hamming cycle problem reduces to this problem in a polynomial number of steps?

Answer (score 1):

1. You mean the Hamilton cycle problem.
2. To reduce the Hamilton cycle problem to this problem, simply set $k$ to the number of vertices in the graph.

Comment: Yes, I meant the hamiltonian cycle problem, but by taking k = number of vertices in the graph aren't we ignoring other cases where k != the number of vertices?

Comment: We don't need to worry about those cases. All we're saying is "If there were a general efficient algorithm for the at-least-$k$-cycle problem, then in particular there would be an efficient algorithm for the case $k=n$, which is the Hamiltonian cycle problem." It's possible that other cases of the problem are easy, and that's fine. (In fact, the $k=3$ version of the problem is always easy.)

Comment: @NiharShah : The Question asks for "the hamming cycle problem reduces to this problem".  This answer shows how Hamiltonian cycle problem instances embed in the collection of this problem instances.  Your comment asks about the instances that are not the image of this reduction, which is nowhere discussed in the Question.